# Trying to convert crmForm to Xrm.Page

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, xrm

So I'm quite new to JavaScript and I need to upgrade this to XRM as the below code has been deprecated. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I'm guessing a start would be `Xrm.Page.ui.create`

```
function setMinutesWorked() {
    var CRM_FORM_TYPE_CREATE = 1;
    var CRM_FORM_TYPE_UPDATE = 2;
    switch (crmForm.FormType) {
        case CRM_FORM_TYPE_CREATE:
            crmForm.all.actualdurationminutes.DataValue = null;
            break;
        case CRM_FORM_TYPE_UPDATE:
            // do nothing
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function setMinutesWorked() {
    var CRM_FORM_TYPE_CREATE = 1;
    var CRM_FORM_TYPE_UPDATE = 2;
    var formType = Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType();
    switch (formType) {
        case CRM_FORM_TYPE_CREATE:
            Xrm.Page.getAttribute("actualdurationminutes").setValue(null);
            break;
        case CRM_FORM_TYPE_UPDATE:
            // do nothing
            break;
    }
}
```

or if the function is just doing this, the following code is enough:

```
function setMinutesWorked() {
    if (Xrm.Page.ui.getFormType() == 1) {
        Xrm.Page.getAttribute("actualdurationminutes").setValue(null);
    }
}
```